# Networking issues when running multiple Docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, network-programming, docker-network

I am currently getting familiar with Docker and one issue I have is launching several Docker containers on the same host machine.
If I run 32 or less containers, everything works fine.
However, if I start more containers, not only my host machine loses internet connection, but also the containers are not able anymore to communicate with each other.

After searching the web, this seems to be a common issue, but no solution worked for me yet.
I tried setting up custom Docker network bridges as well as editing the `/etc/docker/daemon.json`  file.
In any case, if I run `docker network inspect` on the respective network, everything seems fine and each containers has its own IP address correctly assigned.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but netowrking, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [su] (depending on whether you are using it on a server or on a dev machine).